# How to do the following (SQL) as a model / models

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

Busy learning MVC 3 and have come across the following scenario which I would like to implement in the proper/best way using MVC 3 standards.

I have 2 Tables hArticle & lRating in my DB, the hArticle Table basically stores the articles information and the lRating table stores each rating per person. Below is the SQL statement that I would use to obtain the Data I need. (Please note this is for Reading purposes only, I do NOT need the Create, Update & Delete from CRUD)

**SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ArticleID, A.Title, A.Likes, A.Author, 
CASE WHEN SUM(R.Rating) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(R.Rating) END AS 'Rating'
FROM hArticle A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN lRating R ON R.ArticleID = A.ArticleID
GROUP BY A.ArticleID, A.Title, A.Likes, A.Author
```

**This produces the following result:**

```
    1   Article 1     12    Peter Ndlovo    10
    2   Article 2     2     Peter 2         0
    3   Article 3     3     Peter 3         0
    4   Article 4     4     Peter 4         0
```

What is the proper/best way to recreate the following SQL statement in MVC i.e. Do I create a Model mapped to an SQL View or create a Model for Each Table and combine them etc??

Answer (score 0):

create a model that can carry all of the objects that you need for the functionality of that view or you can use a dynamic model with ExpandoObject

view model approach

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx

and dynamic model approach (great article!)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62839/Adventures-with-C-4-0-dynamic-ExpandoObject-Elasti

though if you need simplicity ie. a list of one type of object or just one object than life is simple
just give that object as the model for the view

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way is to decouple everything. In my MVC projects, I have a domain model that reflects the database more or less exactly, this is not part of the MVC architecture but a "Domain Model" project in the same solution. The M of mvc would then be a set of "ViewModels" that reflect the way my Views present data. For the above I would create a model for each table and have them combined in a view model which I would use to display the results.